# Can anyone explain the usecase of jdbc resultset getTimestamp(int,calendar)?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, cachedrowset

I'm talking about this interface method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int,%20java.util.Calendar%29

The most commonly used implementation being the one in cachedrowset:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.java line 6170

You will notice that the implementation does two very weird things:

1) it modifies the calendar passed as argument, even though there is also a return value

2) it extracts all the time information from SQL, **except for the milliseconds**, which come from the calendar passed as argument.

The interface description is rather unclear, but assuming the implementation is correct - What is the point of this method? I can understand a method that would take a calendar to extract just the timezone, without modifying it. But taking a calendar, modifying it, and extracting not only the zone but also the milliseconds...

Does anyone have any insight as to the history/design/reasoning behind this API?

Comment: Looks to me like the person that implemented this `CachedRowSet` didn't understand the JDBC API (there are more nice misinterpretations of JDBC in the reference implementation of `RowSet`). As far as I know the Calendar should be used only for its timezone info, however the API does say "the java.util.Calendar object to use in constructing the timestamp"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Yes that's what i'm thinking - I'm wondering if the implementor was tricked by the phrasing "to construct an appropriate millisecond value for the timestamp" - so they actually copied across the milliseconds...

What's scary is that this implementation can never be "fixed" - it would break the workarounds that people have been using.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an incorrect interpretation of the JDBC API documentation (and unfortunately the `javax.sql.rowset` has more of those incorrect interpretations).

By default a JDBC driver needs to store or retrieve a time or timestamp as if the time stored in the database is in the current timezone of the JVM. As this isn't always what you want, the API provides methods to provide a `Calendar` object, which you need to use to derive the actual timezone to use (I don't know why they didn't use `java.util.TimeZone` instead).

This is specified in [PreparedStatement.setTimeStamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-java.util.Calendar-):

> With a `Calendar` object, the driver can calculate the timestamp **taking into account a custom timezone**. If no `Calendar` object is specified, the driver uses the default timezone, which is that of the virtual machine running the application.

The method `getTimestamp` in `ResultSet` follows (or should follow) these same rules.

So if a database stores time '11:20' and your local timezone is CET (UTC+1), then the retrieved time is 10:20 UTC (11:20 CET). However if I provide a `Calendar` in GMT, the returned time should be 11:20 UTC (12:20 CET).

Answer (score 1):

SQL databases store the date and time value for timestamps in the form of year, month, day, hour min, sec etc. The instance in time these values specify depends on the *timezone* in which they are interpreted (e.g. 2014. january 1. 15:00:00 is not at the same time in Europe than in the USA). The timezone *may* or *may not* be part of the timestamp, depending on the column's type.

The Java [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) classes represent an instance of time regardless of the time zone (or rather in a fixed, UTC timezone).

If the column in the SQL database does not store the timezone info along with the date+time, in order to create a Java `Date` or `TimeStamp` object from such a timestamp requires a timezone so it can point to a specific instance in time (in the reference UTC timezone).

The `ResultSet.getTimestamp()` method in question can be used to get an SQL timestamp data and convert it to a Java `Timestamp` instance using the timezone info set in the parameter `Calendar` object.

Comment: As far as I know - and I implement a JDBC driver - the Calendar object is used for timezone info (default a JDBC driver should use the current timezone of the JVM, this can be inferred from [`PreparedStatement.setTimeStamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-java.util.Calendar-): _" With a Calendar object, the driver can calculate the timestamp taking into account a custom timezone. If no Calendar object is specified, the driver uses the default timezone, which is that of the virtual machine running the application."_

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the javadoc, I edited my post.